# Python Recursive Function - subsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

### What I want to do

I need to Realize a recursive function def k_size_subsets(n, k):
which gets 2 integers n and k, and returns as a list all subgroups of size k of the group {1,2,3,...n} in some order.

Each subgroup in the circled list will be represented by a string of subgroup members. All characters of the string representing a subgroup must be in ascending order from left to right.

(for each string, the characters of the string must be in ascending order. So for example, the string '342' which represents the sub the group {2,3,4} will not be accepted, and the representative string that will be accepted is '234')

Also we know that n ≥ k ≥ 0 and 1 ≤  ≤ 9. I can't use loops, built-in of list and string (except len), set and it might be recursive.

I can build helper functions but a function inside a function is not allowed.

### Examples:

`for subsets(5,3) - [‘123’, ‘124’, ‘125’, ‘134’, ‘135’, ‘145’, ‘234’, ‘235’, ‘245’, ‘345’]`

`for subsets(5,0) - ["]`

### Code:

```
def helper_k_size_subsets(n, k, lst, index, delete, swap_digit_sum, final_sum):
s = lst[index]
if len(s) != k:
    next_number = chr(ord(s[len(s)-1])+1)
    s = s + next_number
    lst[index] = s
    string_sum = get_sum_of_string(0, s[len(s)-(n-k):], 0)
    string_final_sum = get_sum_of_string(0, s, 0)
    if string_final_sum == final_sum:
        return lst
    if string_sum == swap_digit_sum:
        if delete < k - 1:
            delete += 1
        if int(s[-delete]) + 1 == int(s[-delete + 1]):
            next_s = s[:len(s) - delete - 1] + chr(ord(s[len(s) - delete - 1]) + 1)
            lst += [next_s]
            index += 1
            return helper_k_size_subsets(n, k, lst, index, delete, swap_digit_sum, final_sum)
        next_s = s[:len(s)-delete] + chr(ord(s[len(s)-delete])+1)
        lst += [next_s]
        index += 1
        return helper_k_size_subsets(n, k, lst, index, delete, swap_digit_sum, final_sum)
    else:
        return helper_k_size_subsets(n, k, lst, index, delete, swap_digit_sum, final_sum)
else:
    next_number = chr(ord(s[len(s)-1]) + 1)
    s = s[:-1] + next_number
    lst[index] = s
    string_final_sum = get_sum_of_string(0, s, 0)
    if string_final_sum == final_sum:
        return lst
    return helper_k_size_subsets(n, k, lst, index, delete, swap_digit_sum, final_sum)

def get_sum_of_string(index, str, sum):
if index == len(str):
    return sum
sum += int(str[index])
return get_sum_of_string(index+1, str, sum)

def get_sum_by_range(begin, end):
if begin > end:
    return 0
return begin + get_sum_by_range(begin + 1, end)

def k_size_subsets(n, k):
if k == 0:
    return []
swap_digit_sum = get_sum_by_range(n - k + 1, n)
final_sum = get_sum_by_range(1, k)
lst = ['1']
index = 0
return helper_k_size_subsets(n, k, lst, index, 2, swap_digit_sum, final_sum)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler code would be easier to manage:

```
def substrings(n,k,start=1,prefix=""):
    if k == 0:
        return [prefix]
    if start>n:
        return []
    return substrings(n,k-1,start+1,prefix+chr(start+48)) \
         + substrings(n,k,start+1,prefix)
```

output:

```
print(substrings(5,3))
['123', '124', '125', '134', '135', '145', '234', '235', '245', '345']

print(substrings(5,0))
['']
```

The recursion needs to go horizontally by adding the second, third, ... positions starting with the next number.  It also needs to go vertically by getting strings of the same length (k) with the next starting number.

```
1 -> 12 -> 123
           124
           125 
     13 -> 134
           135
     14 -> 145
2 -> 23 -> 234
           235
     24 -> 245
...
```